# NHibernate ICriteria - order by child collection count?

Tags: nhibernate, parent-child

Here is a simple example scenario -

A 'Tag' has many 'Questions'. When I get a list of Tags how do I order by the Tags Question Count using the Criteria API?

I have done this before but haven't touched NH in about 4 months and have forgotten... projections maybe? help!!!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sat down with a fresh pair of eyes and figured it out...  Tags are now ordered by a  propery on the Tags Question collection (views).. which made alot more sence in my domain than ordering by the count of children

```
    public IList<Tag> GetTop(int numberOfTags)
    {
        using (ITransaction transaction = Session.BeginTransaction())
        {

            DetachedCriteria detachedCriteria = DetachedCriteria.For<Tag>()
                    .CreateCriteria<Tag>(x => x.Questions)
                    .AddOrder<Question>(x => x.Views, Order.Desc)
                    .SetMaxResults(numberOfTags)
                    .SetProjection(Projections.Distinct(Projections.Id()));

            IList<Tag> tags = Session.CreateCriteria<Tag>()
                .SetFetchMode<Tag>(x => x.Questions,FetchMode.Join)
                .Add(LambdaSubquery.Property<Tag>(x => x.Id).In(detachedCriteria))
                .SetResultTransformer(new DistinctRootEntityResultTransformer())
                .List<Tag>();

            transaction.Commit();
            return tags;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var tags = Session.CreateCriteria(typeof(Tag))
                  .AddOrder(Order.Asc("Tag.Question.Id")
                  .List<Tag>();

// If that does not work, try:
var tags = Session.CreateCriteria(typeof(Tag))
                  .CreateCriteria("Question", "TagQuestion", JoinType.InnerJoin)
                  .AddOrder(Order.Asc("TagQuestion.Id")
                  .List<Tag>();
```

1. **[Ordering on joined columns.](http://davybrion.com/blog/2008/10/ordering-on-joined-columnsproperties-with-nhibernate/)**
2. **[Ordering the query criteria](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html#querycriteria-ordering)**.

**Edit:** Unless you're deciding against it or your already comfortable with the Criteria API, you should take a look at either **[HQL](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/reference/en/html/queryhql.html)** or **[NHibernate.Linq](http://www.tobinharris.com/past/2008/8/17/linq-for-nhibernate-examples/)**:

```
var tags = Session.Linq<Tag>()
               .OrderBy(tag => tag.Question.Id)
               .ToList();
```

**[Linq to NHibernate: a vast improvement.](http://www.caffeinatedcoder.com/linq-to-nhibernate/)**

Comment: Not exactly what I was after something more like this:- (Which would fail)

Session.Linq<Tag>().OrderBy(tag => tag.Questions.Count).ToList();